# Send all notifyOSD messages to another ubuntu on the network

Tags: networking, notification, notify-osd, notify-send

I want an ubuntu to send a copy of all its notifyOSD messages to another ubuntu on the network. Preferably with a little "addition" to the title that specifies the host name of the ubuntu that generated the notifications.

I searched and found a way to send a custom notification but I want to forward a copy of all notifications. Is there a *fairly simple* way to do this?

Comment: Possible, no doubt in some form, ,*fairly simple* definitely not.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this with `notify-osd` as it does not have any support for talking over the network.